Managing multiple users on a Sambashare that is mounted at /media/user
The way my computer is set up is that I have a drive that boots and runs the OS and then, a 6TB drive that I have the actual samba share on.
However, with the second account I'm trying to set up, it can't access the entire server. User 1 and User 2 are meant to access the server from other machines as a client, so that is where I'm testing it. I've been able to access it locally from the other account just by typing in the password for it (being the same as the one used for the samba share).
I thought that this could be solved by switching the mounting point from a user one (/media/user1) to one I had created myself (/media/storage) however this hasn't changed it at all.
Any recommendations for this?
Edit:
net usershare info --long yielded no result whatsoever. 
The output for testparm -s is:
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
Loaded services file OK.
Weak crypto is allowed by GnuTLS (e.g. NTLM as a compatibility fallback)

Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE

# Global parameters
[global]
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    logging = file
    map to guest = Bad User
    max log size = 1000
    obey pam restrictions = Yes
    pam password change = Yes
    panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
    passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
    passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
    server role = standalone server
    server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
    unix password sync = Yes
    idmap config * : backend = tdb


[printers]
    browseable = No
    comment = All Printers
    create mask = 0700
    path = /var/tmp
    printable = Yes


[print$]
    comment = Printer Drivers
    path = /var/lib/samba/printers


[sambashare]
    comment = 6tb home storage server
    path = /media/storage/6TB-HDD
    read only = No


You've provided no Ubuntu product & release details; nor specifics on how you actually mount, as I'd likely do what you appear to want by modifying your existing mount  (which you didn't specify, which could be how I'd do it, or something different meaning I'd choose another method)

I didn't think the Ubuntu version mattered for this one because it was more related to sambashare itself. It's Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS if that helps in any way. As for the specifics, I don't know, that was just how it mounted itself when I plugged it in so there was nothing deliberate about it on my part.

My only concern about changing the mounting point is that I think it would be undone if I turned off or restarted the computer. Plus I don't know where I should mount it instead. The second one being the main point.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

That is what GROUPs can be used for: toss both in the same group, set samba to that group and it works (tm)

Is this second user ( let's call him user2 ) trying to access /media/user1/XXX on the ubuntu machine locally - as in on the same machine? Or has user2 been set up to access the share of /media/user1/XXXX from another machine - as in a samba client machine? If it's the latter edit your original post and add the output of this command testparm -s and this one net usershare info --long

@Rinzwind Would that be the workgroup? I tried to edit it according to your message but nothing changed in that department. Could you tell me exactly what steps to do?

This is becoming more confusing.
You changed the user from user1 to storage? Do I have this right? storage is a user name?
